How to count documents created within specific month or year using createdAt field in mongoDB?
I'm building an admin dashboard and i want to count users created in given month or year. I'm using the countDocuments() method with the query param "createdAt" but the result is 0 and i'm expecting a result of 2.
Here is the code:
const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

const newClientThisMonth = await User.countDocuments({
    createdAt: { $eq: currentYear },
});

The "newClientThisYear" variable is returning 0 instead of 2. I know i'm using the countDocuments() method in the wrong way with this field but with other fields like the "role" field everything is working fine.
const clientUsersCount = await User.countDocuments({ role: "user" });

So, how will you do it if it was you ?

Are you taking into account that getMonth() returns a 0-based value?

Yes and that's why I used the getFullYear() in this example but what's is the problem? Why it's not working? Is there a solution or do I have to change the CountDocuments() with another method? @mykaf

Why is the getMonth() portion included in the question if you don't use it? What steps have you taken to debug countDocuments()? I'm not familiar with mongoose or mongodb, but I suspect createdAt is a timestamp, but you're only passing a year. 2024 != 2024-10-16 10:43 (or however it's stored in mongodb).

@mykaf I have console logged the return value of the CountDocuments method. And your suspicion are correct, createdAt is a timestamp.

Your current code looks to me that it is comparing a date to simply a year/month, like 2024 or 10. I don't think it is expected to return any data.
One of the canonical ways to do this in MongoDB would be comparing the year and month together(and only year and month) with $year and $month operators.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            // your input here
            "yearInput": 2024,
            "monthInput": 10
          },
          "in": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$yearInput",
                  {
                    "$year": "$createdAt"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$monthInput",
                  {
                    "$month": "$createdAt"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "count"
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thank you !!!! It's first time i'm learning this.
